Discord Bot reply to my messege with text and provided data. Python
I want write command "!addpoints "numOfPoints"" and bot should reply to this message this: You added "numOfPoints" points.
I tried make it, like it is on photo:code but I got this errors: errors errors1

First off, post your code and errors as text, not images.
You're trying to use ctx.reply() as print. You shoul write send a single string instead.
ctx.reply(f"You added {numOfPoints} points")

